# Are AND&OR circuits P-complete?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity

The AND&OR gate is a gate which is given two inputs and returns their AND and their OR. Are circuits made only out of the AND&OR gate, without fanout, capable of doing arbitrary computations? More precisely, is polynomial time computation logspace reducible to AND&OR circuits?

My motivation for this problem is rather strange. As described [here](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=104772.0), this question is important for computation inside the computer game [Dwarf Fortress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarf_Fortress).

Comment: Such circuits are monotone, and hence are far from P-complete.

Comment: @David Harris: At first sight, I thought so, too, but that reasoning is not correct because a log-space reduction can augment the input with its negation!

Comment: It can be, note that the monotone Boolean formula evaluation is complete for $\sf{NC^1}$ under $\sf{AC^0}$.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand what you mean by AND&OR gate, it is basically a comparator gate which takes two input bits $x$ and $y$ and produces two output bits $x\wedge y$ and $x\vee y$. The two output bits $x\wedge y$ and $x\vee y$ are basically min$(x,y)$ and max$(x,y)$.

Comparator circuits are built by composing these comparator gates together but **allowing no more fan-outs other than the two outputs produced by each gate**. Thus, we can draw comparator  circuits using the notations below (similarly to how we draw sorting networks).

[image]

We can define the *comparator circuit value problem* (CCV) as follows: given a comparator circuit with specified Boolean inputs, determine the output value of a designated wire. By taking the closure of this CCV problem under logspace reductions, we get the complexity class [CC](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo:C#cc), whose complete problems include natural problems like lex-first maximal matching, stable marriage, stable roomate.

In [this recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.2721), Steve Cook, Yuval Filmus and I showed that even when we use AC$^0$ many-one closure, we still get the same class CC. To the best of our knowledge at this point, NL $\subseteq$ CC $\subseteq$ P. In our paper, we provided evidence that CC and NC are incomparable (so that CC is a proper subset of P), by giving oracle settings where relativized CC and relativized NC are incomparable. We also gave evidence that CC and [SC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SC_%28complexity%29) are incomparable.

Answer (score 0):

(the answer is not eligible because it refers to separate AND, OR gates without fan out restriction)

The following article is on topic: [Majority-Vote Cellular Automata, Ising Dynamics, and P-Completeness](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9701118)

> We show that in three or more dimensions **these systems can simulate
>   Boolean circuits of AND and OR gates, and are therefore P-complete**.
>   That is, predicting their state t time-steps in the future is at least
>   as hard as any other problem that takes polynomial time on a serial
>   computer.
>
> (...)
>
> The Monotone Circuit Value problem, where AND and OR gates are allowed
>   but NOT gates are not, is still P-complete for the following reason:
>   using De Morgan’s laws (...), we can shift negations
>   back through the gates until they only affect the inputs themselves.
>   Thus any Circuit Value problem can be converted to a Monotone Circuit
>   Value problem with some of the inputs negated. This kind of
>   conversion, from an instance of one problem to an instance of another,
>   is called a reduction.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer? I failed to see the connection between "these systems" and the AND&OR circuits mentioned above.

Comment: I have read the paper 2 years ago. It is devoted to P-completeness and monotone logic circuits. I leave final interpretation to reader, because I can't remember details now. It is for sure a good article though, especially if Itai seems to be confused. More: isn't the bold text in my quote the answer – that AND/OR logic circuits are P-complete?

Comment: Ok you are right. I will maybe leave my answer, maybe it will be helpful to someone.

Comment: It is a well-known fact that the problem of evaluating monotone circuits which consist of AND gates and OR gates, where each gate is allowed to have **fanout 2**, is P-complete. The circuit problem mentioned by the orignal poster imposes **fanout restriction**, and thus it's not know to be P-complete.

Comment: @dai do you have a ref for that? seems like fanout 2 could allow arbitrary DAGs. is that not right?

Comment: @vzn Circuit evaluation is in P. A reference for the fact Dai mentioned is Cook and Nguyen's book "Logical foundations of proof complexity".